# Cross gdb can't find python

Tags: python, gdb, mingw, cross-compiling, msys2

I've built a cross gdb with python support on Windows using MSYS2/MINGW64. I have installed python in MINGW64, i.e. I have `python2.7.exe` in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` and this address is in my path.

I get the following errors when I run gdb

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site`
```

I also added `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib` where I have the `libpython2.7.dll.a` but I still get the same error.

I also tried installing python on windows and set up all the paths, but still the same error.

How can I make gdb find python?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set environment variables:

```
PYTHONPATH=C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7;C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload;
```

PYTHONHOME variable refers to python interpreter:

```
PYTHONHOME=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\python.exe
```

I built my own gdb under msys2 and it works after setting correct environment variables:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.19]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tiit>echo %PYTHONHOME%
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\pyhon.exe

C:\Users\tiit>echo %PYTHONPATH%
C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7;C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python2.7\lib-dynload;

C:\Users\tiit>C:\msys64\home\tiit\gdb-7.11-bin\bin\x86_64-linux-gnu-gdb.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1.20160801-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb)
```

My command line for configure was:

```
./configure --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/tiit/gdb-7.11-bin --with-python=/mingw64/bin/python.exe --enable-static=yes
```